# how to remove the red line under the pom.xml?

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I use IDEA, there is **red-bold-font** label in my `pom.xml`, I can solve the red line error, but I have no ideas about the red-bold-font error. How to disable the inspection?

My project runs very well. I can't remove the dependency.

Above is all my information and the picture is in below:

[image]

Comment: This is a bug of IntelliJ IDEA. No problem.

Comment: Why are you excluding all `*.java` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise the correct config is 
 <includes><include>**/*Test*.java</include></includes>，the picture above is a pom.xml of special module created by the web framework in my company.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `fork` param for surefire.

> Surefire versions prior 2.14 used the parameter `forkMode` to configure
>   forking.

Please look at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

It might be better to update your surfire plugin.